# I can't catch any pokemon or get items from PokeStops. How can I fix it?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am at level 15 and have 200 Pokemon. I am not able to catch any Pokemon. They come out and run away just after they get in the Pokeball. I am not able to get anything from PokeStops either. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you used bots or spoofed your location before?

Answer (score 0):

You can try spinning a poke stop again and again for like 40 times until it diminishes or you just simply wait. This happens when you move around too often in the game, like being in a vehicle, gps spoofing, etc..

Comment: This is more of a comment, not an answer.